# Connect Twilio Outbound call to Watson Assistant

Tags: twilio, watson-assistant

I'm trying to make an outbound call using Twilio's API and connect the number that i'm calling to my Watson Voice Agent(that is linked to my Watson Assistant). I can call the phone but the call isn't redirected to the assistant.

I'm using the Twilio API for java. I've set my Twilio number's SIP trunk to use my Voice Agent's SIP

This is the method implementation

```
public String callPhone(String to, String from)throws URISyntaxException{
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

        Call call = Call.creator(

                new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber(to),
                new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber(from),
                new URI("http://www.example.com/sipdial.xml"))
                .create();

        return call.getSid();
```

This is my call:

```
tw.callPhone(phoneIWantToCall,TwilioPhoneNumber);
tw.callPhone("sip:TwilioPhoneNumber@us-south.voiceagent.cloud.ibm.com",TwilioPhoneNumber);
```

I receive a call from my Twilio number but it isn't directed to my Assistant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The issue here is that you are creating two separate calls that don't connect.

Instead of generating two calls using the REST API, you need to return [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml) from the URI in your URI parameter that connects the call to the person to the Watson agent. So you should set the URI in your `callPhone` method to a URL in your own application. And that URI should return TwiML that includes [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) to connect to the agent in this case using [`<Sip>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/sip).

The TwiML should look a bit like this:

```xml
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Sip>sip:TwilioPhoneNumber@us-south.voiceagent.cloud.ibm.com</Sip>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Let me know if that helps at all.